# thrust::minmax_element argumen list doesn't match

Tags: cuda, thrust

I have following small piece of code that uses thrust::minmax_element to find out the min and max of a struct of 3 floats. But the compiler always says argument list doesn't match. I am using CUDA 6.5 under Mac OS 10.9

```
  struct Float3 {float x, y, z;};
  struct Comparator : public binary_function<Float3, Float3, bool> {
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const Float3& a, const Float3& b) const
    {
      return  a.x > b.x;
    }
  };
  Float3 a[10];
  thrust::minmax_element(device_ptr<Float3>(a),
                         device_ptr<Float3>(a) + 10,
                         Comparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please provide a complete example that someone can copy, paste, and compile to see the issue, without adding anything or changing anything.

```
Float3 a[10];
```

creates data on the host.  You cannot wrap a pointer created like that with `thrust::device_ptr`.  It must be used to refer to data that is on the device.  `a` is not on the device.  The following code compiles (and runs) cleanly for me in CUDA 6.5:

```
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>


  struct Float3 {float x, y, z;};
  struct Comparator : public thrust::binary_function<Float3, Float3, bool> {
    __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const Float3& a, const Float3& b) const
    {
      return  a.x > b.x;
    }
  };

int main(){
  Float3 a[10];
  Float3 *d_a;
  cudaMalloc(&d_a, 10*sizeof(Float3));
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, 10*sizeof(Float3), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  thrust::minmax_element(thrust::device_ptr<Float3>(d_a),
                         thrust::device_ptr<Float3>(d_a) + 10,
                         Comparator());
}
```

Note that the above code will actually *compile* without error, even if you use `a` instead of `d_a`  (since they are both raw pointers, thrust cannot tell the difference at compile-time).  But that usage of `a` is an error, and the code will throw an error if you try to run it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out where the problem is. I initially defined the struct Comparator within the function. After I moved it outside of the function, the error was fixed.